# React Native app crashes on first launch after update to Android 13 (tools v33)

Tags: android, react-native

After I upgraded my React native app from 31 to 33 SDK version, my app started to crash after the first launch.

No errors are shown

On the second launch, everything works fine.

I assume that the problem is in the storage (maybe async) because if (after the second successful launch) I clear the app's cache and storage - the app will crash again on the first launch.

React native version: 0.69.7

Here is my build.gradle files

build.gradle:

```
import org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.condition.Os

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'
ext {
buildToolsVersion = "33.0.0"
minSdkVersion = 21
compileSdkVersion = 33
targetSdkVersion = 33

        // We use NDK 23 which has both M1 support and is the side-by-side NDK version from AGP.
        ndkVersion = "23.1.7779620"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath('com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.1')
        classpath("com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin")
        classpath("de.undercouch:gradle-download-task:5.0.1")
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }

}

allprojects {
repositories {
maven {
// All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
}
maven {
// Android JSC is installed from npm
url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
}
mavenCentral {
// We don't want to fetch react-native from Maven Central as there are
// older versions over there.
content {
excludeGroup "com.facebook.react"
}
}
google()
maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
}
}
```

app/build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: "com.google.gms.google-services"

apply plugin: "kotlin-android"

import org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.condition.Os
import com.android.build.OutputFile

/\*\*

* The react.gradle file registers a task for each build variant (e.g. bundleDebugJsAndAssets
* and bundleReleaseJsAndAssets).
* These basically call `react-native bundle` with the correct arguments during the Android build
* cycle. By default, bundleDebugJsAndAssets is skipped, as in debug/dev mode we prefer to load the
* bundle directly from the development server. Below you can see all the possible configurations
* and their defaults. If you decide to add a configuration block, make sure to add it before the
* `apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"` line.
* 
* project.ext.react = \[
* // the name of the generated asset file containing your JS bundle
* bundleAssetName: "index.android.bundle",
* 
* // the entry file for bundle generation. If none specified and
* // "index.android.js" exists, it will be used. Otherwise "index.js" is
* // default. Can be overridden with ENTRY_FILE environment variable.
* entryFile: "index.android.js",
* 
* // https://reactnative.dev/docs/performance#enable-the-ram-format
* bundleCommand: "ram-bundle",
* 
* // whether to bundle JS and assets in debug mode
* bundleInDebug: false,
* 
* // whether to bundle JS and assets in release mode
* bundleInRelease: true,
* 
* // whether to bundle JS and assets in another build variant (if configured).
* // See http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Variants
* // The configuration property can be in the following formats
* //         'bundleIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
* //         'bundleIn${buildType}'
* // bundleInFreeDebug: true,
* // bundleInPaidRelease: true,
* // bundleInBeta: true,
* 
* // whether to disable dev mode in custom build variants (by default only disabled in release)
* // for example: to disable dev mode in the staging build type (if configured)
* devDisabledInStaging: true,
* // The configuration property can be in the following formats
* //         'devDisabledIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
* //         'devDisabledIn${buildType}'
* 
* // the root of your project, i.e. where "package.json" lives
* root: "../../",
* 
* // where to put the JS bundle asset in debug mode
* jsBundleDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/debug",
* 
* // where to put the JS bundle asset in release mode
* jsBundleDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/release",
* 
* // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
* // require('./image.png')), in debug mode
* resourcesDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/debug",
* 
* // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
* // require('./image.png')), in release mode
* resourcesDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/release",
* 
* // by default the gradle tasks are skipped if none of the JS files or assets change; this means
* // that we don't look at files in android/ or ios/ to determine whether the tasks are up to
* // date; if you have any other folders that you want to ignore for performance reasons (gradle
* // indexes the entire tree), add them here. Alternatively, if you have JS files in android/
* // for example, you might want to remove it from here.
* inputExcludes: \["android/**", "ios/**"\],
* 
* // override which node gets called and with what additional arguments
* nodeExecutableAndArgs: \["node"\],
* 
* // supply additional arguments to the packager
* extraPackagerArgs: \[\]
* \]
  \*/

project.ext.react = \[
enableHermes: true,  // clean and rebuild if changing
\]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"
apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle"

/\*\*

* Set this to true to create two separate APKs instead of one:
* - An APK that only works on ARM devices
* - An APK that only works on x86 devices
* The advantage is the size of the APK is reduced by about 4MB.
* Upload all the APKs to the Play Store and people will download
* the correct one based on the CPU architecture of their device.
  \*/
  def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

/\*\*

* Run Proguard to shrink the Java bytecode in release builds.
  \*/
  def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

/\*\*

* The preferred build flavor of JavaScriptCore.
* 
* For example, to use the international variant, you can use:
* `def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc-intl:+'`
* 
* The international variant includes ICU i18n library and necessary data
* allowing to use e.g. `Date.toLocaleString` and `String.localeCompare` that
* give correct results when using with locales other than en-US.  Note that
* this variant is about 6MiB larger per architecture than default.
  \*/
  def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc:+'

/\*\*

* Whether to enable the Hermes VM.
* 
* This should be set on project.ext.react and that value will be read here. If it is not set
* on project.ext.react, JavaScript will not be compiled to Hermes Bytecode
* and the benefits of using Hermes will therefore be sharply reduced.
  \*/
  def enableHermes = project.ext.react.get("enableHermes", false);

/\*\*

* Architectures to build native code for.
  \*/
  def reactNativeArchitectures() {
  def value = project.getProperties().get("reactNativeArchitectures")
  return value ? value.split(",") : \["armeabi-v7a", "x86", "x86_64", "arm64-v8a"\]
  }

android {
ndkVersion rootProject.ext.ndkVersion

    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.devote"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        buildConfigField "boolean", "IS_NEW_ARCHITECTURE_ENABLED", isNewArchitectureEnabled().toString()
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                arguments "-DBUILD_TESTS=FALSE"
                targets "devote"
            }
        }
    
        if (isNewArchitectureEnabled()) {
            // We configure the NDK build only if you decide to opt-in for the New Architecture.
            externalNativeBuild {
                ndkBuild {
                    arguments "APP_PLATFORM=android-21",
                        "APP_STL=c++_shared",
                        "NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION=clang",
                        "GENERATED_SRC_DIR=$buildDir/generated/source",
                        "PROJECT_BUILD_DIR=$buildDir",
                        "REACT_ANDROID_DIR=$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/ReactAndroid",
                        "REACT_ANDROID_BUILD_DIR=$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/ReactAndroid/build",
                        "NODE_MODULES_DIR=$rootDir/../node_modules"
                    cFlags "-Wall", "-Werror", "-fexceptions", "-frtti", "-DWITH_INSPECTOR=1"
                    cppFlags "-std=c++17"
                    // Make sure this target name is the same you specify inside the
                    // src/main/jni/Android.mk file for the `LOCAL_MODULE` variable.
                    targets "devote_appmodules"
                }
            }
            if (!enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture) {
                ndk {
                    abiFilters (*reactNativeArchitectures())
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    if (isNewArchitectureEnabled()) {
        // We configure the NDK build only if you decide to opt-in for the New Architecture.
        externalNativeBuild {
            ndkBuild {
                path "$projectDir/src/main/jni/Android.mk"
            }
        }
        def reactAndroidProjectDir = project(':ReactAndroid').projectDir
        def packageReactNdkDebugLibs = tasks.register("packageReactNdkDebugLibs", Copy) {
            dependsOn(":ReactAndroid:packageReactNdkDebugLibsForBuck")
            from("$reactAndroidProjectDir/src/main/jni/prebuilt/lib")
            into("$buildDir/react-ndk/exported")
        }
        def packageReactNdkReleaseLibs = tasks.register("packageReactNdkReleaseLibs", Copy) {
            dependsOn(":ReactAndroid:packageReactNdkReleaseLibsForBuck")
            from("$reactAndroidProjectDir/src/main/jni/prebuilt/lib")
            into("$buildDir/react-ndk/exported")
        }
        afterEvaluate {
            // If you wish to add a custom TurboModule or component locally,
            // you should uncomment this line.
            // preBuild.dependsOn("generateCodegenArtifactsFromSchema")
            preDebugBuild.dependsOn(packageReactNdkDebugLibs)
            preReleaseBuild.dependsOn(packageReactNdkReleaseLibs)
    
            // Due to a bug inside AGP, we have to explicitly set a dependency
            // between configureNdkBuild* tasks and the preBuild tasks.
            // This can be removed once this is solved: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/207403732
            configureNdkBuildRelease.dependsOn(preReleaseBuild)
            configureNdkBuildDebug.dependsOn(preDebugBuild)
            reactNativeArchitectures().each { architecture ->
                tasks.findByName("configureNdkBuildDebug[${architecture}]")?.configure {
                    dependsOn("preDebugBuild")
                }
                tasks.findByName("configureNdkBuildRelease[${architecture}]")?.configure {
                    dependsOn("preReleaseBuild")
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include (*reactNativeArchitectures())
        }
    }
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file('debug.keystore')
            storePassword 'android'
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
        }
        release {
              storeFile file('devout.keystore')
              storePassword 'Devoutkey'
              keyAlias 'devoutalias'
              keyPassword 'Devoutkey'
            }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        release {
            // Caution! In production, you need to generate your own keystore file.
            // see https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }
    
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path file('src/main/cpp/vote-saver/CMakeLists.txt')
            version '3.18.1'
        }
    }
    
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits.html
            // Example: versionCode 1 will generate 1001 for armeabi-v7a, 1002 for x86, etc.
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a": 1, "x86": 2, "arm64-v8a": 3, "x86_64": 4]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        defaultConfig.versionCode * 1000 + versionCodes.get(abi)
            }
    
        }
    }

}
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: \["\*.jar"\])

    //noinspection GradleDynamicVersion
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:31.2.2')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'
    implementation("com.michael-bull.kotlin-retry:kotlin-retry:1.0.9")
    
    implementation "androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.3.9"
    
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    
    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.facebook.fbjni'
    }
    
    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-network-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
        exclude group:'com.squareup.okhttp3', module:'okhttp'
    }
    
    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-fresco-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
    }
    
    debugImplementation fileTree(dir: 'libs-debug', include: ['*.aar', '*.jar'], exclude: [])
    releaseImplementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.aar', '*.jar'], exclude: [])
    implementation "ee.nx-01.tonclient:ton-client-kotlin:0.0.54"
    
    if (enableHermes) {
        //noinspection GradleDynamicVersion
        implementation("com.facebook.react:hermes-engine:+") { // From node_modules
            exclude group:'com.facebook.fbjni'
        }
    } else {
        implementation jscFlavor
    }

}

if (isNewArchitectureEnabled()) {
// If new architecture is enabled, we let you build RN from source
// Otherwise we fallback to a prebuilt .aar bundled in the NPM package.
// This will be applied to all the imported transtitive dependency.
configurations.all {
resolutionStrategy.dependencySubstitution {
substitute(module("com.facebook.react:react-native"))
.using(project(":ReactAndroid"))
.because("On New Architecture we're building React Native from source")
substitute(module("com.facebook.react:hermes-engine"))
.using(project(":ReactAndroid:hermes-engine"))
.because("On New Architecture we're building Hermes from source")
}
}
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
from configurations.implementation
into 'libs'
}

apply from: file("../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)

def isNewArchitectureEnabled() {
// To opt-in for the New Architecture, you can either:
// - Set `newArchEnabled` to true inside the `gradle.properties` file
// - Invoke gradle with `-newArchEnabled=true`
// - Set an environment variable `ORG_GRADLE_PROJECT_newArchEnabled=true`
return project.hasProperty("newArchEnabled") && project.newArchEnabled == "true"
}
```

gradle-wrapper.properties:

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5-bin.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
```

React-native info:

```
System:
OS: macOS 12.6.2
CPU: (8) arm64 Apple M1
Memory: 109.50 MB / 8.00 GB
Shell: 5.8.1 - /bin/zsh
Binaries:
Node: 18.12.1 - /usr/local/bin/node
Yarn: 1.22.19 - /opt/homebrew/bin/yarn
npm: 8.19.2 - /usr/local/bin/npm
Watchman: 2023.03.27.00 - /opt/homebrew/bin/watchman
Managers:
CocoaPods: Not Found
SDKs:
iOS SDK: Not Found
Android SDK:
API Levels: 31, 33
Build Tools: 29.0.2, 30.0.2, 30.0.3, 31.0.0, 33.0.0, 33.0.1, 33.0.2
System Images: android-31 | Intel x86 Atom_64, android-31 | Google APIs ARM 64 v8a, android-33 | Google APIs ARM 64 v8a
Android NDK: Not Found
IDEs:
Android Studio: 2022.1 AI-221.6008.13.2211.9619390
Xcode: /undefined - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
Languages:
Java: 11.0.17 - /usr/bin/javac
npmPackages:
@react-native-community/cli: Not Found
react: Not Found
react-native: Not Found
react-native-macos: Not Found
npmGlobalPackages:
*react-native*: Not Found
```

I tried:

- Change Gradle's version (thought that building was not right)
- change react-native versions

Comment: Hey there, Do you have more details about this issue, Have you fixed it already? I'm facing the same issue and nothing found yet, I've tried to remove the Lottie also added some new configurations but nothing helping.

I've even got the same Device which crashing but it's not when connecting it to via USB to the Android studio only crashing once opening it after installing the APK.

Comment: related? https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/37674

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve the problem. There the trouble was with the FirebaseMessaging service in the Manifest. I just removed it and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

React native map works on Android 13  but platform version less than 33 works fine but if platform version is 33 the app crashes

Answer (score -1):

For many people this seems to be related to Hermes,
can you try to disable it inside your app/build.gradle.
Don't forget to clean and rebuild.

```
project.ext.react = [
    enableHermes: false,  // clean and rebuild if changing
]
```

Otherwise, try to open your Android studio and check the Logcat for more details on the error and provide them, please.

Comment: Disabling Hermes didn't help
I tried using Flipper, it gave me a such error:
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
"com.devote.java.MyFirebaseMessagingService" on path: DexPathList[[zip file
"/data/app/~~ykhtl_P9M9NiHAszg_fFTw==/com.devote--SMPYa6B8NNrDa-7CfBRYw==/base.apk"], nativeLibraryDirectories= [/data/app/ykhtl_P9M9NiHAszg_fFTw==/com.devote--SMPYa6B8NNrDa-7CfBRYw==/lib/arm64, /data/app/ykhtl_P9M9NiHAszg_fFTw==/com.devote--SMPYa6B8NNrDa-7CfBRYw==/base.apk!/lib/arm64- v8a, /system/lib64, /system/system_ext/lib64, /vendor/lib64, /odm/lib64, /my_carrier/lib64]]